# Line break in docbook document

Tags: xml, docbook, dblatex

I want to force a line break on some places in my docbook document, but I don't want to start a new paragraph.
I have the following code:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<book xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook" version="5.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <info><title>Some Project</title></info>
    <chapter>
        <title>Some Documentation</title>
<section>
    <title>aa.h File Reference</title>
<para>some text<sbr/>some more text</para>

<para>some text<literallayout>
</literallayout>some more text </para>
</section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Problem here is that the result with `<literallayout>` (in XMLMind and dblatex) has too much space (as if we have a new paragraph) and the the `<sbr\>` is (officially) not allowed here (but shown nicely in XMLMind and dblatex).

Any solutions / ideas?

Comment: I would say, you should distinguish different goals: line break within your editing environment and line break within output targets. What exact do you want to achieve: line breaks while editing or line breaks after transformation (i.e. pdf)?

Comment: I want to, automatically, achieve it in the resulting output (and preferably also in the editor like XMLmind DocBook Editor Personal Edition, http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/download.shtml#download_xbe_perso ; I'm not affiliated in any way with XMLMind).

Comment: In such case - there is 2 different tasks to solve separately: editor in one way, output in the another way - there is no strict connection between them (though it could be). I'll try to look at it and let you know in several days. I also use XMLMind, but Pro edition, though not affiliated with this company.

Comment: How about using a custom processing instruction, such as `<?extraspace?>`?

Comment: @mzjn I was hoping on a build in feature of docbook and not something to be added by the user.

Comment: There is nothing built in. DocBook markup is about content and structure. Presentation and styling preferences (such as the amount of whitespace produced by an empty paragraph) are handled by style sheets. The `<sbr>` element is an exception for very rare situations only (https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/sbr.html).